# Getting Error cors "Request header field responsetype is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response" in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, cors

Error in the browser console

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https:///some_site/resource1/downloadCSV' from origin 'https://some_site' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field responsetype is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

check the API Method

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def downloadCSV(request):
    request_body = request.data
    response = HttpResponse(
        some_service.call_some_other_service(),
        content_type="application/octet-streamf",
    )
    today = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    filename = f"{today}_Data.csv"
    response["Content-Disposition"] = f'attachment; filename="{filename}.csv"'
    return response
```

main/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
.............
    "corsheaders",
   ........
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

I can't do it because the other response type header is failing, Please suggest how to allow the responseType =bob so that I will able to download API.

```
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    # ...
    'responsetype',
    # ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these settings with Django **`settings.py`**

```
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders', # <-------- this
    'myapp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', # <-------- this
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'sales_company_app.get_user_instance.RequestMiddleware',
]



REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
}


CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True # <-------- this
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",    # React (FrontEnd Url) # <-------- this
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = '*' # <-------- this
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["http://192.168.1.155:8000/"] # (Api Base Url) <-------- this (allow csrf_token) for doing whitelist
```