# CORS Errors while accessing the REST API in REACT

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I have installed the django-cors-headers and configured the following in my settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'atpdocuments',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",  # or specific domains
    # other allowed origins...
]
```

After adding this also im not able make a request from React. Getting the following error

`Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.`

I have tried the above methods but still iam getting the cors errors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77042722/19205926

Comment: Your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` is empty list you've to add hosts in it